# indexOf confusion in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var err = "No msg";

if(myVar.indexOf(err) > -1){
//this means myVar NOT containing No msg
}
```

is my logic correct? I'm getting my if statement if executing..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check if a string **does not** contain a substring, use

```
if(myVar.indexOf(err) === -1) {
```

Or

```
!~myVar.indexOf(err)
```

`~` is [BitWise NOT operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT) *"Performs the NOT operator on each bit. NOT a yields the inverted value (a.k.a. one's complement) of a."* and `!` is [Logical NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_(!)), so converting the index to Boolean result.

[`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) returns -1 if substring is not found.

Comment: **0** is greater than **-1** I suppose!

Comment: or `!~myVar.indexOf(err)` :p

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Check comment _"this means myVar NOT containing No msg"_, OP is not trying to find if string contains substring, OP wants to check if the string does not contain

Comment: Oh! Just understood What OP meant to be.

Comment: @Tushar In that case `< 0` would be the correction not `=== -1`!

Comment: Doesn't help that the string has "no" in it ... looks like a double negative when it actually isn't :p

Comment: @RayonDabre From Docs, _Returns -1 if the value is not found._, also `< 0` will not work for `'saa'.indexOf('s') < 0`

Comment: @Tushar ... testing result of indexOf using `< 0` or `=== -1` return the same boolean value in all cases I can think of

Comment: @Tushar, `'saa'.indexOf('s') < 0` will return **0** which is satisfies the `> -1` condition!

Comment: @RayonDabre - `< 0` is not a better or worse correction than `=== -1` - in the context of the question, they produce identical results ... `===` may be nanoseconds faster too

Comment: @Tushar - was half kidding, caused some interesting comments when I suggested it once before :p ... of course, I said using `!~` would get you laid at JSconf :p

Answer (score 0):

No your logic is not correct. indexof return -1 if sub string is not present.

```
    var err = "No msg";

if(myVar.indexOf(err) == -1){
//this means myVar NOT containing No msg
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var err = "No msg";
if(myVar.indexOf(err) > -1){
//this means myVar contains "No msg"
}
else{
//this means myVar does NOT contain "No msg"
}
```

Or

```
var err = "No msg";
if(myVar.indexOf(err) === -1){
//this means myVar does NOT contain "No msg"
}
```

`indexOf` returns the index of the first character that is the string being matched.
so if

```
myVar = "There is No msg in here";
myVar.indexOf("No msg") == 9; //true
```

But

```
myVar = "There is nothing in here";
myVar.indexOf("No msg") == -1; //true
```

This is because `indexOf()` returns -1 when it can not find what it was looking for.